# If $\sqrt{18-6\sqrt{5}} = \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{b}$, then which of the following relations are true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck at a question.

> If $\sqrt{18-6\sqrt{5}} = \sqrt{a}- \sqrt{b}$, then which of the following is true:
>
> 1. $a+b= 18$
> 2. $a+b= 16$
> 3. $a+b= 20$
> 4. $a-b= 18$

I tried to first take the main root to the other side which made the R.H.S **$2\sqrt{ab}$** but after that, I can't solve this any further.

Can someone help me in telling me what to do next?

Comment: Are $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I am just a IX grade student, I don't understand that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider

$$(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)^2=a+b-2\sqrt{ab}=18-6\sqrt5=18-2\sqrt{45}$$

For integer $a,b$, integral part of the expression is 18.

So $a+b=18$.

Comment: Thanks but how can it be $18+2√45$ when it is $18 - 6√5$?

Comment: and also we must use $(a-b)^2$

Comment: Yah some typo. Fixed

Comment: btw $-6\sqrt5=-2\sqrt{5\cdot3^2}=-2\sqrt{45}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{18-6\sqrt 5}&=\sqrt{18-2\sqrt{5\times 3^2}}\\&=\sqrt{(15+3)-2\sqrt{15\times 3}}\\&=\sqrt{(\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{3})^2}\\&=\sqrt{15}-\sqrt 3\end{align}$$
So, $a=15,b=3$.

Comment: Yeah let me try that.... Thanks @mathlove